# Android Files: if I copy a .zip file to /sdcard/Download, the uri will be wrong

Tags: java, android, file-manager, file-browser

I got a requirement that we can open a .zip file(replaced with .activity) through my app. I set the manifest.xml like

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:scheme="file" />
     <data android:scheme="content" />
     <data android:host="*" />
     <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
     <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.activity" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I open a file named 'test.activity' which is 'test.zip' actually with the code below.

```
public void chooseFile(CallbackContext callbackContext) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
```

First I push 'test.activity' to /sdcard/Download and I got a uri like `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ftest.activity`

Then I click **Downloads** and copy the file to **Downloads** as well(/sdcard/Download), it will be named with test(1).activity automatically.  I thought the correct uri should be

`content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2Ftest(1).activity`

but I got a uri like

```
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/805
```

So the 'intent-filter' I mentioned at the beginning will become invalid. Could anyone tell me why the end of this uri becomes a number?

Comment: `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/805` That is a pretty normal content scheme obtained from a Download 'partition'. A valid uri. That provider does it like that. Get used to it.

Comment: The number is the document id of the file.

Comment: Your approach can maybe work if you first make a folder in the Downloads and put your file there. Untested.

Answer (score 0):

On some devices. when selecting a file from the download directory will return the wrong uri. So you need to change it

You can refer here

https://github.com/Turtlebody/android-media-picker/issues/7

Comment: Thanks. But his problem can be reproduced on my Google Pixel, I wonder why native file managers do this.

Comment: This problem is caused by the manufacturer. We cannot interfere.

Comment: The code in the link tries to obtain a classic file path and uses the File class. The uri was ok and the File approach is wrong.